# speech_recognition can't import pyaudio; ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, pycharm, speech-recognition, pyaudio

I am trying to program a voice assistant using python and the SpeechRecognition library. But when I execute my program, it runs for about 2 secs and then throws the following Error

`[0:02] Decoding of audio.mp3 finished.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/USERNAME/PycharmProjects/jarvis/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 108, in get_pyaudio
    import pyaudio
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaudio'`

I have already spent some hours trying different solutions but none seem to work for me.

I am on ubuntu if that helps

Comment: Have you tried `pip install pyaudio`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out. There was nothing wrong with my installation. It seems to be a bug in the integrated Terminal of pycharm. When I moved into my project dir with my linux shell and executed my script everything worked just fine. I don't know, why it didn't work with the built in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Try making sure it's installed for Python 3, not 2, and run `pip3 install pyaudio` if it is on pip.

Comment: How can I check that?

Comment: Just run the `install` command and if it is installed, it will tell you. Also, make sure that the Python 3 version of `pyaudio` has that name and it doesn't have anything extra on it.

Comment: So I just ran `pip install pyaudio` as well as `pip3 install pyaudio` both of which resulted in the following Error: ` src/_portaudiomodule.c:28:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include "Python.h"
              ^~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1`

Comment: Ah. Run this then. `sudo apt-get install python3-dev` assuming that you are using Ubuntu.

Comment: Hm. Try this now, what they mention in this Github issue. https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/issues/314

Comment: I tried the proposed command `pip install pyaudio --global-option="-I/path/to/the/dir/of/portaudio.h" ` but -I isn't a valid option for this command. On SO I came across this modified version of the command `pip install --global-option='build_ext' --global-option='-I/usr/local/include' --global-option='-L/usr/local/lib' pyaudio
` which returns the same Error as before (fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory)

Answer (score 0):

Installing these packages additionally along with ***SpeechRecognition*** and ***PyAudio*** resolved all the conflicts:

```
pip3 install beautifulsoup4

pip3 install googletrans

pip3 install gTTS

pip3 install gTTS-token

pip3 install pip

pip3 install pipwin

pip3 install playsound

pip3 install PyAudio

pip3 install pylint

pip3 install pyobjc

pip3 install pyttsx3

pip3 install setuptools

pip3 install SpeechRecognition

pip3 install Translator

brew install flac

brew install portaudio
```

With these, ***SpeechRecognition*** and ***googletrans*** were able to work just fine:

If your IDE is VS Code, then set the python language server to Pylance instead of Default in the settings.json file. This worked for me!

Else, set it to Jedi server.

Hope this helps!